# Recursive write permissions for Apache user

Tags: ssh, ftp, prestashop, file-permissions, lamp

Hello I am trying to install Prestashop on my LAMP server via SSH but when run the installation process. I got these error.

[image]

The Prestashop files are located in `/var/www/html` What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Find the Apache user](https://serverfault.com/questions/125865/finding-out-what-user-apache-is-running-as) and change the owner of the folders recursively.

E.g., if the Apache user is `apache` then:

`chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/config /var/www/html/cache`...

Comment: @markyeoj Then change `apache:apache` to `youruser:yourgroup`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Morris Mukiri,

I tried all the chmod, chown, chgrp , but the prestashop error message still there .

Your suggestion of "allow apache do writes" worked !

**setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on**

**setsebool -P httpd_unified on**

**setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting on**

These few lines did the magic.

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the permissions for the document root folder

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/
   ```

   You might want to add yourself to the same group as apache using

   ```
   useradd -G {group-name} username
   ```
2. Try adding a rule in Selinux to allow apache do writes

   ```
   sudo setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on
   sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified on
   sudo setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting on
   ```