# Prestashop installation needs to write critical files in the folder var/cache. please review the permissions on your server

Tags: permissions, prestashop, centos7, prestashop-1.7

I had tried a change the permission as the permission as the error body says it's a permission issue but when i applied the solution still got the same error.

```
Prestashop installation needs to write critical files in the folder var/cache. 
please review the permissions on your server.
```

I tried:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59981507/12717902

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/prestashop
```

**But this didn't work for me**

environment : Centos 7 | prestashop 1.7.7.1 | php 8.1.8 | mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a solution i've been looking for everywhere on the net i wanted to post the solution i found somewhere on Stackoverflow here which wasn't voted enough hope this will help more people.

The solution is:

**sudo setsebool -P httpd_enable_cgi on**

**sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified on**

**sudo setsebool -P httpd_builtin_scripting on**

this is the link for the question i took from the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29139124/12717902